# Cannot print a static variable - affected by another constant

Tags: php

Given this code:

```
class Weather
{
    const START_DATE_HOLDER = "XXSSXX";
    const END_DATE_HOLDER   = "XXEEXX";

    //THIS STATIC IS NOT REFERENCED BUT AFFECTS "$Q" , omitting this eliminates issue
    public static $Q_ANYDAY = 'A ' . START_DATE_HOLDER;

    public static $Q = 'test';

    public static function getDaysWx(string $wxDate)
    {
        print($wxDate);
        print(self::START_DATE_HOLDER);
        print(self::$Q);
        print('Hello');
    }
}
```

Invoked with

```
Weather::getDaysWx('2023-03-25');
```

prints

```
2023-03-25
XXSSXX
```

and does **NOT** print 'test' nor "hello".  (I suspect its erroring on the third print.)

In my test driver I have

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

but no errors are displayed.

Why does it not print the 3rd and 4th lines.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SELF::` to address the constant or static

```
public static $Q_ANYDAY = 'A ' . SELF::START_DATE_HOLDER;
```

Or as in your original

```
static $Q_ANYDAY = 'https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/xx%20city%20xx/' . 
        SELF::START_DATE_HOLDER . 
        '/' . 
        SELF::END_DATE_HOLDER . 
        '?unitGroup=us&elements=datetime%2Ctempmax%2Ctempmin&include=days&key=xxx&contentType=json';
```

The first 2 lines of your code

```
print($wxDate);
print(self::START_DATE_HOLDER);
```

address the variables correctly, hence those 2 lines work

Comment: Thanks - that was it - can you explain why it fails at the 3rd print when it's not referenced. but the first two appear.

Comment: Well I get a `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "START_DATE_HOLDER" in tst.php on line` error from your original code

Comment: The 3rd line references `$Q` not the static with the error (`$Q_ANYDAY`)- that's the part that threw me.